Button with PlainButtonStyle doesn't get tapped when the window is inactive
I'm writing a MacOS app. I'm displaying a button. When the app is inactive, if I click the button, the button's tap event gets triggered as the same time as the window is activated. So far so good.
However if I now add .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle()) to my button which is the desired look, it doesn't get tapped when the window is inactive. The first click activates the window and I need a second click to trigger the button.
Button {
  print("tapped!")
} label: {
  Image(systemName: "doc.on.doc")
    .resizable()
    .frame(width: 14, height: 14)
    .padding(5)
}
.buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())


See https://christiantietze.de/posts/2024/04/enable-swiftui-button-click-through-inactive-windows/

And that was published a month ago. What a wonderful world. Works like a charm.

Whether a view can receive the click event without their window being activated is controlled by the acceptsFirstMouse(for:) method. When the button style is .plain, the button is no longer backed by an NSButton (whose acceptsFirstMouse method would have returned true), so you can no loner "click-through" the button.
You can wrap a NSViewRepresentable around the button, and override acceptsFirstMouse to return true.
This is the code from this blog post
extension SwiftUI.View {
    public func acceptClickThrough() -> some View {
        ClickThroughBackdrop(self)
    }
}

fileprivate struct ClickThroughBackdrop<Content: SwiftUI.View>: NSViewRepresentable {
    final class Backdrop: NSHostingView<Content> {
        override func acceptsFirstMouse(for event: NSEvent?) -> Bool {
            return true
        }
    }

    let content: Content

    init(_ content: Content) {
        self.content = content
    }

    func makeNSView(context: Context) -> Backdrop {
        let backdrop = Backdrop(rootView: content)
        backdrop.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return backdrop
    }

    func updateNSView(_ nsView: Backdrop, context: Context) {
        nsView.rootView = content
    }
}

Example usage:
Button("Foo") {
    print("triggered")
}
.buttonStyle(.plain)
.acceptClickThrough()


Thanks, this is great. Hopefully some Apple engineer will come across this...
